# How can I create an arrayList and use it as a check?

Tags: java

I need to create a list of string(text used in the app are numbers). The list should contain number starting from 30-99. I need to use this list to check for a condition. Basically, when the user inputs a number and if the number exists between 30-99, a button called "saveButton" needs to be disabled.

How can I create an array list containing numbers from 30-99 and use the check condition instead of hard coding the values to my list?

Comment: please share your code that you have tried

Comment: Can't you just check `if(number < 30 || number > 99)` ?

Comment: Use HashMap instead where your number is the key and value is true or false

Comment: @parohy Presumably containing every number?

Comment: The number is entered by the user. It can be 1, it can be 999. When the user enters the number, the data is saved on the fly.

Comment: If all you want to know is whether the input is between two numbers, you dont need to store an array of strings with those numbers, just do a condition as Randy mentioned above, convert your string input using this: int foo = Integer.parseInt("30");

Comment: @shmosel yes containing every number.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8

```
IntStream.range(30, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: We're not into assisted suicide here.

Comment: It's a... not very good answer, but it does answer the question @EricLeschinski

Answer (score 0):

You can just fill your list with numbers you want (30-99) and then check if user's input is in the list with java.util.List.contains(Object o). If yes than disable "saveButton".